# Pwmconfig not writing to /etc/fancontrol

Tags: fancontrol

So I decided to switch from Win8 to Ubuntu for dev (all the team uses..), and so I have the it-seems-classic problem of 'fan was quiet under Win and blasts with Ubuntu'

I've tried everything - loaded all the apps - read all the info I could find. And I still  can't get it to be quiet.

I have identified the GPU to be the problematic fan, since I could successfully shut down the CPU fan while testing with `pwmconfig` (although it won't write a conf file after).

So I run this `pwmconfig`, and I even login as root to try and create a config file manually in /etc/`fancontrol` but without success.

The log below show too blasting fans but it's actually only one - the other one has been triggered up by pwmconfig...

Any idea how I could solve this?

sensors works

```
pwmconfig works - at least as a diagnosis
fancontrol would work if I could write  a proper config file I guess.

*-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: Turks XT [Radeon HD 6670/7670]
       vendor: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI]
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm pciexpress msi vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=radeon latency=0
       resources: irq:47 memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:fe620000-fe63ffff ioport:e000(size=256) memory:fe600000-fe61ffff




root@Pegasus-DX4860:~# sensors
radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +87.5°C  

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 0:         +24.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 1:         +30.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 2:         +29.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)
Core 3:         +28.0°C  (high = +80.0°C, crit = +98.0°C)

it8772-isa-0a30
Adapter: ISA adapter
in0:          +0.94 V  (min =  +0.82 V, max =  +0.04 V)  ALARM
in1:          +2.22 V  (min =  +2.74 V, max =  +3.00 V)  ALARM
in2:          +2.88 V  (min =  +1.60 V, max =  +0.84 V)  ALARM
in3:          +2.98 V  (min =  +2.29 V, max =  +0.82 V)  ALARM
in4:          +2.93 V  (min =  +0.08 V, max =  +1.27 V)  ALARM
in5:          +2.22 V  (min =  +0.80 V, max =  +0.77 V)  ALARM
in6:          +2.22 V  (min =  +2.40 V, max =  +2.03 V)  ALARM
3VSB:         +3.36 V  (min =  +3.29 V, max =  +1.44 V)  ALARM
Vbat:         +3.36 V  
fan1:           0 RPM  (min =   10 RPM)  ALARM
fan2:        2566 RPM  (min =  405 RPM)
fan3:        4115 RPM  (min =   13 RPM)
temp1:        +30.0°C  (low  = +66.0°C, high = +97.0°C)  sensor = thermal diode
temp2:        +30.0°C  (low  = +68.0°C, high = -47.0°C)  ALARM  sensor = thermal diode
temp3:        +29.0°C  (low  = -30.0°C, high = +50.0°C)  sensor = Intel PECI
intrusion0:  ALARM
```